# need help on this scenario , what is standard?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, scenarios

I have the scenario in my online exam asp.net mvc application.

where, as student logged in-> he selects test/Exam -> then load the set of questions.

Now I am populating the questions one by one like in wizard. this wizard is totally on the fly (means dynamically creates all elements),build in javascript and jquery.

**scenario is :** when student gives the answer for the question is it ok to hold answer in collection, and send to controller at once on last question submission or immediately save on "Next" button click ? which is better ? I think on Next button click will better . but I want to know standard way for this. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a "standard". it depends on the requirements.

If the next question depends on the result of the previous answer you should submit it immediate. 
If not, I don't see a problem to submit all the answers at once. This also might save you the work of storing the answers in the Session/TempData